# Подключение пользователей к боту на голосовой канал по реакции

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

У меня есть бот, который по команде подключается к голосовому каналу.

Также есть **on_raw_reaction_add(payload)**. Бот добавляет две реакции.

Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь по нажатию реакции (например, ) автоматически заходил на канал к боту? Ну или чтобы заходил на канал по ID

Comment: Насколько я знаю, никак, но можно наоборот

Comment: Можно сделать, чтобы он по команде подключался к голосовому каналу, к пользователю. По другому никак :(